# search an array of string in a large string and check if any exist using linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have an array of string

```
var searchString = new string[] {"1:PS", "2:PS"};
```

and a large result string eg;

```
var largeString = "D9876646|10|1:PS^CD9876647100|11|2:PS"
```

how do I check if any of the options in searchString exist in the largeString? 
I know it can be done via loop quite easily but I am looking for an other way around since I need to append the following as search clause in linq query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ for it with a simple [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) call, like this:

```
var hasAny = searchString.Any(sub => largeString.Contains(sub));
```

However, this is as slow as a `foreach` loop. You can find the answer faster with a regex constructed from `searchString`:

```
var regex = string.Join("|", searchString.Select(Regex.Escape));
var hasAny = Regex.IsMatch(largeString, regex);
```

Comment: Except the `Regex` won't mesh well with being added to a LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your LINQ provider (assuming it isn't LINQ to Objects), you may want to add individual tests for each member of `searchString`. The best way to do this is probably using [`PredicateBuilder`](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#predicatebuilder)

```
var sq = PredicateBuilder.New<dbType>();

foreach (var s in searchString)
    sq = sq.Or(r => r.largeString.Contains(s));

q = q.Where(sq);
```